# Absence of the required field does not cause an error. typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

In my nodejs project i have a controller

```
const addQuestion = async(req : Request, res : Response) => {
    try {
        const question: IQuestion = req.body;
        if (!(await checkExist(question))) {
            return res.status(409).send();
        }
        
        redisAsync.set(question.question, question.answer);

        return res.status(200).send();
    }
    catch (err) {
        return res.status(422).send();
    }
}
```

And an interface

```
interface IQuestion {
    question : string;
    answer   : string;
}
```

So, I expect to catch an error, when I pass to the controller JSON without question and/or answer fields, then give 422 code, but it not happens and code executes without required fields in object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While TypeScript is statically typed, it still executes as JavaScript that's dynamic. **TypeScript doesn't check types at runtime.** Therefore when you cast `any` value to an `IQuestion`, TypeScript expects you to make sure it is an `IQuestion`.

Basically, you need to manually verify the fields. A [type guard / type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) is ideal for this:

```js
function isQuestion(question: any): question is IQuestion {
    return typeof question === 'object'
        && typeof question.question === 'string'
        && typeof question.answer === 'string';
}

const addQuestion = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const question: IQuestion = req.body;
        if (!isQuestion(question)) {
            return res.status(422).json({ error: 'Expected an IQuestion as body' });
        }
        if (!(await checkExist(question))) {
            return res.status(409).send();
        }

        redisAsync.set(question.question, question.answer);

        return res.status(200).send();
    }
    catch (err) {
        return res.status(422).send();
    }
}
```